# ".txt file" or "txt file" or "*.txt file"?

Tags: word-choice, software

What is the correct form to address all files having the same extension? For example, files *a.txt* &  *b.txt*.

I found these forms used:

> 1. .txt files
> 2. txt files
> 3. *.txt files

Context: I am writing a user manual for software. There is a lot about file structures, so I need a brief form of "all files with the extension txt" in expressions like:

> Copy all *.txt files from folder A to folder B
>
> Each object is stored in 5 different *.txt files

Comment: Please provide more context.  Any or none of those might be correct depending on the situation.

Comment: _All files with the extension .txt_ is the clearest to me

Comment: With your examples, *.txt makes sense to me, however that is because I am from the DOS days. Someone dragging files off a windows explorer may have a different view of the world

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a sentence the fully correct form would be:

> "All files with a txt extension" or "All .txt files."

An asterisk would make the sentence very hard to read.

Comment: but the asterisk would replace "all."

Comment: I don’t like the dot in the English. In fact, I don’t like the shades-of-CP/M “txt” for “text”, either.

Comment: The filename extension here is "txt", not ".txt", with "." being the separator between filename and extension. So if you're referencing the "extension" you ought to drop the separator.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you establish a usage convention early on that allows you to write naturally:

> Note: in this document, a reference to (some type of) file" is used to mean a file with a particular file extension.
>
> ```
> A file with this extension    will be called a ___ file:
> .TXT                          text 
> .BAT                          batch 
> .DOC                          Word
> .SLDDRW                       Solidworks
> (etc)
> ```

Then, you can say things like

> Move all text files to the readme directory and all Word files to the recycle bin.

Comment: If you're writing for nontechnical Windows users, this is important, because file extensions are probably turned off by default (so people only know files by the program that opens them). On the other hand, I use phrases like *E-book (.epub) files* when I'm writing for a technical audience, because they need to know both the word that we show to other people and the file extension itself. Your audience makes a huge difference in what is "correct".

Answer (score 2):

The "*" is a very technical term, and I would restrict its use to only direct commands:

> Type: 'copy *.txt c:\temp'
>
> Select "*.txt" in the copy dialog.

When you're writing a sentence, you would want it to read well.  Imagine someone reading it aloud:

> Copy all files with the "txt" extension. *-- Reads like a sentence.*

The other alternatives are less desirable for various reasons:

> Copy *.txt files.  *-- Read it aloud and it sounds goofy.*
>
> Copy all files ending in ".txt".   *-- Reads OK, but "txt extension" is more technically correct unless you've got some really novice users who don't know what an extension is.*
>
> Copy all *.txt files.   *-- Bit redundant, since "all" and "asterix" mean the same.*